# How to make VSCode extension configuration property name uppercase?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

For VSCode settings UI, the configuration property names are constructed using capital letters as word breaks. i.e. gitMagic.someName is converted to 'Git Magic: Some Name'

How do I make all letters of a word as uppercase? I'm looking for a way to get the property name 'GIT Magic'. Couldn't find anything from the documentation - https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#Configuration-schema

Comment: I'm not sure you can. Besides, if you take a look at the official website (https://git-scm.com/), that's actually the correct spelling of "Git", it's not an abbreviation. :)

Comment: Ohh Git was just an example, I needed it for other names. Seems like it isn't possible, however.  Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not currently possible; see [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/103592) and [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/70589) VSCode issues.

The list of acronyms and other terms with inner capitalization is [hardcoded](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/f732547a3d548a640e5120eca4bfb59cbedc3c48/src/vs/workbench/contrib/preferences/browser/settingsLayout.ts#L229-L248) in the VSCode source:

```js
export const knownAcronyms = new Set<string>();
[
    'css',
    'html',
    'scss',
    'less',
    'json',
    'js',
    'ts',
    'ie',
    'id',
    'php',
    'scm',
].forEach(str => knownAcronyms.add(str));

export const knownTermMappings = new Map<string, string>();
knownTermMappings.set('power shell', 'PowerShell');
knownTermMappings.set('powershell', 'PowerShell');
knownTermMappings.set('javascript', 'JavaScript');
knownTermMappings.set('typescript', 'TypeScript');
```

(These exports are not reachable via the extension API.)